# How to format new datepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

i use DatePicker like this

```
       <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200sp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false">
        </DatePicker>
```

this how they look is

[image]

How to change DatePicker format to be dd/MM/yyyy, and how to change the months name to be like "Januari, Februari, Maret, April, Mei, ... [indonesian]" ?

Comment: Those attributes are based on system-wide user settings. If you want to change them, it's probably easier to just create your own `DatePicker`, or use a third-party implementation that allows you to set them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom months i suggest you to take String array

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", .........so on};
```

either take switch statement

```
String monthName;
switch(mMonth){
    case Calendar.JANUARY:
        monthName = "Januari";
        break;
    case Calendar.FEBRUARY:
        monthName = "Februari";
        break;
```